# Can decltype used to get the type of an argument?

Tags: c++, templates, decltype

I trying to build a (bit) nicer way to create a delegate from the [Impossibly Fast Delegate](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11015/The-Impossibly-Fast-C-Delegates) by using type deduction. However, I'm running into some problems.

Here's the function I'm trying to simplify :

```
template<typename T, void(T::*TMethod)(E)>
static Delegate<E> create(T * object) { /* ... */ }
```

When you call this function, it looks like this :

```
auto del = Delegate<int>::create<A, &A::foo>(&a);
```

What I would like to end up with is something like :

```
auto del = create_delegate(&a, &A::foo);
```

I thought that decltype could do the trick, but somehow it doesn't work (using VS2012) :

```
template<typename E, typename T>
Delegate<E> create_delegate(T * obj, void (T::*method)(E))
{
    return Delegate<E>::create<T, decltype(method)>(obj);
}
```

I get error C2975: 'Delegate::create' : invalid template argument for 'TMethod', expected compile-time constant expression.

Any ideas?

Comment: Is it necessary for you to be able to decide the method at runtime, or is compile-time good enough ?

Comment: You're passing the address of the member function as a parameter to the function `create_delegate`. Being a parameter, it is *not* a constant inside the function. Also, you need to pass the *value* of that address to `Delegate::create`, not the *type*.

Comment: @MartinJ Hmm, I'm not sure. You mean, doing something like `create_delegate<&A::foo>(&a)` ? If so, I think it's fine.

Comment: @dyp Oh, right. This is looking more impossible that I thought.

Comment: @subb AFAIK there's no general way to simplify it. The general problem is that for `template<typename T, T value> integral_constant;`, you cannot deduce the type and pass the value from the same expression (AFAIK). The only way I know is to use a macro that duplicates the expression, e.g. `#define MAKE_CONSTANT(EXPR) integral_constant<decltype(EXPR), EXPR>`. Similarly, `deduce(&A::foo).value<&A::foo>()` is possible, where `deduce` deduces the type, and `value` passes the value to the template.

Comment: (Another problem is that `A::foo` could be overloaded; if that's the case you'll need to select one overload from the overload set, e.g. by casting or by *not* deducing the type.)

Answer (score 0):

Why not using std::function?

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

struct X {
    void fn(int) {
        std::cout << "Hello\n";
    }
};

template<typename T, typename R, typename A>
std::function<R(A)> create_delegate(T& obj, R (T::*method)(A))
{
    return std::bind(method, &obj, std::placeholders::_1);
}

int main() {
    X x;
    auto delegate = create_delegate(x, &X::fn);
    delegate(1);
}
```

Comment: The problem with std::function is they are not comparable. This means that I cannot store them in a container and later remove them by searching the container.

Comment: @subb You can write a comparison via [`std::function::target`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function/target), but admittedly not in all cases.

Comment: @dyp interesting. I'll look into it.